# Combine first column of n sheets to one colume

Tags: google-sheets

So in one spreadsheet file we have n sheets.

| Sheet1 |
| --- |
| Names |
| a |
| b |

| Sheet2 |
| --- |
| Names |
| b |
| c |
| d |

and so on.. assume n sheets with n values in the first column

Then there's one super sheet.
Super sheet

| Supersheet | Supersheet | Supersheet | Supersheet |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | Sheet2 | Sheet3 | ... |
| Names | Count |  |  |
| a | 1 |  |  |
| b | 2 |  |  |
| c | 1 |  |  |
| d | 1 |  |  |

Assume A1:1 is a list of all of the names of the sheets we want to fetch names from. We want the names pasted into A3:A.

My first thought was to do
`=unique(filter({INDIRECT(A1&"!A3:A");INDIRECT(B1&"!A3:A");INDIRECT(C1&"!A3:A")},{INDIRECT(A1&"!A3:A");INDIRECT(B1&"!A3:A");INDIRECT(C1&"!A3:A")}<>""))`
and expand, but that doesn't take care of N sheets.

So what I thought I could do was
`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(A2:C2&"!A2:A3"))`
but that only takes care of sheet1. INDIRECT doesn't work with arrayformula

So what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either use some script or put your sheets in array {} and pre-program it:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(Sheet1!A1&"!A3:A"); 
        INDIRECT(Sheet2!A1&"!A3:A")}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

since this is one column future sheets can be added this way:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(Sheet1!A1&"!A3:A"); 
        INDIRECT(Sheet2!A1&"!A3:A");
IFERROR(INDIRECT(Sheet3!A1&"!A3:A"));
IFERROR(INDIRECT(Sheet4!A1&"!A3:A"))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image: 0]

`IMPORTRANGE` would be:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id", Sheet1!A1&"!A3:A"); 
        IMPORTRANGE("id", Sheet2!A1&"!A3:A");
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("id", Sheet3!A1&"!A3:A"));
IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("id", Sheet4!A1&"!A3:A"))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

ofc, every importrange formula needs to be authorized separately